# How to upgrade PowerShell version

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

Lately, firing up PowerShell, I noticed that there is a phrase that says:

> Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements!
> https://aka.ms/PSWindows

So why not trying it following the actual Microsoft documentation:

1. I run `$PSVersionTable` and the version installed is 5.1
2. I run `winget search Microsoft.PowerShell` and it says that version `7.2` is available as well as the `7.3 preview` version
3. I run `winget install --id Microsoft.Powershell --source winget` and version `7.2` is installed
4. I run `$PSVersionTable` again and I'm still on `5.1`

[image]

Let's try to install it through [dotnet](https://C:%5CUsers%5Cfranc%5COneDrive%5CDesktop%5CPowerShell.png):

1. I run `dotnet tool install --global PowerShell` and the terminal says `Tool 'powershell' (version '7.2.6') was successfully installed.`
2. I run `$PSVersionTable` and I'm still on `5.1`

[image]

I'm following the current Microsoft documentation, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Powershell 7 (core) is its own application. Search for `pwsh.exe` and run that

Comment: That is true, `pwsh.exe` made the trick. But why I cannot set PowerShell 7 as the default PowerShell?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani PS 7 isn't fully compatible with PS 5.1, so it's best to keep both installed in parallel. And why bother, when `pwsh` is even shorter to type than `powershell`.

Comment: Good point, I was just curious. Thank you

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani In case you are wondering what the changes from PS 5.1 to PS 7.x are, here is a good overview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to upgrade it, as the other answer suggests (they should cohabit), but you can default to the newer one in windows terminal.

This blog showed me how, it's very simple:

https://www.codyhosterman.com/2020/05/defaulting-windows-terminal-to-powershell-7-x-core/

1. open settings and click 'open json file' at the bottom.
2. replace the default guid with the one from the ps7 section.
3. save and restart terminal

Thanks, cody!

Comment: This was useful. Thx

3yrs+ later, seems its now easier by just going to Settings > selecting the "Default profile" on the GUI